# Auto creating folders when using System.IO.File.Move

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, move, .net

I'm updating an old winforms app which moves files to new locations using regex and System.IO.File.Move

Under windows 7, the old app worked fine. If a folder didn't exist, File.Move would create it

```
System.IO.File.Move("c:\stuff\a.txt","c:\stuff\a\file.txt");
System.IO.File.Move("c:\stuff\b.txt","c:\stuff\b\file.txt");
System.IO.File.Move("c:\stuff\c.txt","c:\stuff\c\file.txt");
```

However, under Windows 8 it seems that I have to manually create each folder in the path first. I get an error if I try and move to a folder that doesn't exist yet. Anyone know a way around this? I'd rather not have to create each folder

NOTE: The new, updated app is on WPF rather than winforms. Not sure if that's relevant

Comment: I had the exact same problem.  There is no work-around available. I overloaded the Move method with an extension method.  This is not a lot of work, and your code doesn't require a lot of changes either.

Comment: You will get an DirectoryNotFoundException, if the path specified in sourceFileName or destFileName is invalid.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Before you `File.Move()` you could do:

```
new System.IO.FileInfo("c:\\stuff\\a\\file.txt").Directory.Create();
```

The above will create the "stuff" and "a" folders if they don't exist.

Answer (score 3):

By 2019:

```
        if (!File.Exists(destination)) {
            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(destination);
        }
        File.Move(origin, destination);
```

and don't forget to add:

```
using System.IO;
```